# Rails 4: Using ActionView helpers in model works in development env but not in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I use the following code in one of my models

```
def jasper_amount
    ActionController::Base.helpers.number_to_currency(amount)
end
```

I know that it breaks MVC. However, in this case it is the best solution. I have to pass data to Jasper via the Ruby Java Bridge and formatting in Jasper would be much more complicated.

Calling `object.jasper_amount` from the rails console works fine and prints the expected results. This works fine in development and production.

Now, to pass the data to Jasper I first have to create an xml version of the object's attributes using `object.to_xml(methods: [:jasper_amount]).to_s` This works in development but not in production. In production the value for `jasper_amount` that is passed to Jasper is "0.00 €". However, if I remove `number_to_currency` from `def jasper_amount` (just  returning unformatted `amount`) it works. What's even more confusing is the fact that calling `jasper_amount` from the rails console in productions works. I guess the culprit must be `to_xml`, but I have no idea why it works in development and not in production.

Comment: what is the exception message. Do it relatived to the gem file setting?

Comment: show us your code and your project, and let us know the log/console output , so that we can debug for you.

Comment: @cenyongh There is no exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with Ruby Java Bridge (rjb) and BigDecimal. If you use BigDecimal with rjb, you have to include the "BigDecimal" gem in your Gemfile. Otherwise all your BigDecimals will be 0 (and that all over your app!)